# чтение с конца файла

Tags: java

У меня есть логи игры, которые читаются в программе и если там есть определенная строка программа выполняет действие, но эти строки могут быть по нескольку раз в одном файле логов. Мне нужно, чтобы bufferreader читал файл с конца и дальше, как это сделать?

Comment: Что, логи такие большие, что зачитать сразу весь файл не получится?

Comment: так файл читается, но при каждом перезапуске программы эти строки снова и снова находятся, но мне нужно чтобы они искались в процессе игры, т.е чтобы reader читал с конца и дальше

Comment: Так заставьте его запоминать позицию, до которой он уже читал.

Comment: я и спрашиваю как это реализовать

Comment: `но при каждом перезапуске программы эти строки снова` что если на каждый перезапуск создавать отдельный файл с логами?

Comment: интересно, но как?

Comment: Мне кажется тут вопрос даже в другом. Зачем приложению читать собственные логи?

Comment: нет, приложение одно, но оно читает логи игры одной

Comment: У класса [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) есть методы Mark и Reset. Вы, значить, описания их посмотрите...

Comment: Нужно решение только с использованием стандартной библиотеки или сторонние тоже годятся?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что нужно открыть файл на чтение и потом читать новые строки по мере их появления, т.е. программа должна ждать и обрабатывать новые строки, которые добавляются в файл внешней программой?

Comment: да, любое решение